# Auto-scroll dialog/modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to auto-scroll a dialog/modal window in pure javascript (No CSS, HTML5 etc). I've tried creating a MouseEvent:

```
let evt = new MouseEvent('Wheel', {});
evt.deltaY = 200 * timerCounter;
evt.initEvent('wheel', true, true);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

but the window refuses to move.

When I use scrollTo():

```
window.scrollTo(0, 200 * timerCounter);
timerCounter++;
```

it just moves the background window and not the dialog.

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: could you add the HTML for the modal you're trying to scroll? I'm guessing your answer is to select that element, and do element.scrollTo() instead of window

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it's possible like this:

```
$('.Scroll_div_class').animate({scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 1500);
```